# touch input using WPF/C#: how to define a threshold to tell apart clicks from panning

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, multi-touch, panning

I am currently developing an application using WPF and a (multitouch) capacitive touchscreen monitor, which is recognized by Windows as a native touch device, i.e. it doesn't need any additional drivers.

When I use a WPF button, and click it using touch, I get a clicked event. My problem is that some of my users don't perform a clean click, but the move the touch cursor for some pixels when they touch, so my app doesn't recognize a click event anymore.

Is there a way to define a threshold of movement that Windows will not interprete as a panning gesture, but recognize it as a click instead?

Comment: I have no idea if it's used in touch screens, but with mouse drag/drop operations there is a `SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance` value used to determine the min amount you must drag before triggering a drag operation. Perhaps there is something similar for touchscreen interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this implementation - 32 pixel is used for defining the threshold.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Willbe.Extensions;

namespace Kiolyn.Wpf
{
  public static class TouchAssist
  {
    public static bool GetTouchAsClick(DependencyObject obj)
      => (bool)obj.GetValue(TouchAsClickProperty);

    public static void SetTouchAsClick(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
      => obj.SetValue(TouchAsClickProperty, value);

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectOnMouseOver.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TouchAsClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "TouchAsClick",
          typeof(bool),
          typeof(TouchAssist),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnTouchAsClickChanged));

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectOnMouseOver.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    private static readonly DependencyProperty LastExecuteTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "LastExecuteTime",
          typeof(DateTime),
          typeof(TouchAssist),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty TouchDownPositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "TouchDownPosition",
          typeof(Point),
          typeof(TouchAssist),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    static void OnTouchAsClickChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ev)
    {
      if (d is Button button)
      {
        button.IsManipulationEnabled = true;

        button.TouchDown += (s, e) =>
        {
          button.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left)
          {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent
          });
          button.ClearValue(LastExecuteTimeProperty);
          button.SetValue(TouchDownPositionProperty, e.GetTouchPoint(Application.Current.MainWindow).Position);
        };
        button.TouchUp += (s, e) =>
        {
          var command = button.Command;
          var parameter = button.CommandParameter;
          if (command != null && command.CanExecute(parameter) && button.GetValue(TouchDownPositionProperty) is Point touchDownPosition)
          {
            var touchUpPosition = e.GetTouchPoint(Application.Current.MainWindow).Position;
            var dx = Math.Abs(touchUpPosition.X - touchDownPosition.X);
            var dy = Math.Abs(touchUpPosition.Y - touchDownPosition.Y);
            if (dx < 32 && dy < 32)
            {
              // Should be treated as click
              // Mark the last execute time
              button.SetValue(LastExecuteTimeProperty, DateTime.Now);
              command.Execute(parameter);
            }
          }
        };
        button.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) =>
        {
          if (button.GetValue(LastExecuteTimeProperty) is DateTime lastExecuteTime && DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastExecuteTime).Milliseconds < 300)
          {
            e.Handled = true;
            button.ReleaseMouseCapture();
          }
          button.ClearValue(LastExecuteTimeProperty);
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Button wpf:TouchAssist.TouchAsClick="True"/>
```